# DNS Server Issue

Tags: server, dns, bind

I have set up my own DNS server on my Linux Ubuntu 22.04 Server using bind 9. However, I am encountering an issue. I aim to configure the DNS server to handle all sites with a subdomain of rizsolution.com. If the request is for rizsolutions.com, it should be forwarded to the IP address 64.31.43.226. For subdomains like subdomain.rizsolutions.com, the server should check the entries, but currently, it is not forwarding the request. My domain is connected with hoster.pk, and other subdomains are linked to our own server. When I make a request for rizsolution.com, it displays an 'unable to access' message. Can you guide me on whether I can add its outer IP entry in my forwarder? I am unable to access my main site using this DNS configuration.

**Configuration files**

named.conf.options file

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion yes;
        max-cache-size 5000000;
        listen-on { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
        forwarders {
        64.31.43.226; my rizsolutions.com ip bard told me to do this 
        1.1.1.1;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        9.9.9.9;
        39.39.39.39;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
};
```

named.conf.local file

```
gpt and bard told me to make these changes, but when I implement them, my domain is working, and the subdomain is not
  
zone "rizsolutions.com" IN {
        type stub;
        masters { 64.31.43.226; }; 
};

zone "rizsolutions.com IN {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/forward.zone";
};

zone "2.50.20.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/reverse.zone";
};
```

forward.zone file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dns.rizsolutions.com. root.dns.rizsolutions.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      dns.rizsolutions.com.
dns     IN      A       192.168.110.202
dev     IN      A       192.168.110.206
dc      IN      A       192.168.110.201
```

reverse.zone file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dns.rizsolutions.com. root.dns.rizsolutions.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      dns.rizsolutions.com.
202     IN      PTR     dns.rizsolutions.com.
206     IN      PTR     dev.rizsolutions.com.
201     IN      PTR     dc.rizsolutions.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server is not going to be authoritative for the base domain, the stub entry at top with the master server is the correct entry for the base.  Remove this:

zone "rizsolutions.com IN {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/forward.zone";
};

Then you will need to add zones for each subdomain you want to resolve.  Ex:

zone "sub1.rizsolutions.com IN {
type master;
file "/var/lib/bind/sub1.rizsolutions.com.zone";
};

Also, as shown in this entry, the typical location for storing zone files is in /var/lib/bind, not in etc.  etc is static config files, the dynamic data files go in /var/lib/bind.  Add the entries in your data file for your subdomain.  If this is internal only, no other changes are needed.  If you want the subdomains resolvable on the public internet, you need to point each subdomain to your server from the base domain dns server.

Finally, you do not need the forwarder: 64.31.43.226; - forwarders are for resolving unknown domains.  You want your upstream DNS servers as forwarders.  In this case, you are pointing your base domain to 64.31.43.226, so the forwarder is not necessary.